# How to get Spring Data Mongo Aggregations to work like they do with mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am attempting a simple projection using Spring Data Mongo's Aggregation API.

The pipeline step I want to do is:

```
{
  $project : {
    "account._id" : 1,
    "account.position" : 1
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried (along with a ton of other tweaks because nothing seems to work):

```
ProjectionOperation project1 = Aggregation.project("account._id", "account.position");
```

However, even though this is how the documentation says to do it here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.projection

The actual document that is rendered by that projection ends up looking like:

```
{
  $project : {
    _id : "$account._id",
    position : "$account.position"
  }
}
```

Which works completely differently than the projection that I am wanting to use.

Does anyone know how to get a projection like I want out of Spring Data Mongo Aggregation API, or is this a bug I need to report?

---

**Update 8/29/2019 - Adding more data to build out the context:**

Two collections are involved:  "groups" and "accounts"
A group looks something like this:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("..."),
  name: ..., 
  ownerId: ObjectId("..."),
  other stuff...
}
```

An account looks something like this:

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("..."),
  position : "ABC",
   memberships : [{
    groupId: ObjectId("..."),
    otherstuff: ...,
  }],
  other stuff...
}
```

My whole aggregation looks like this and works as desired in mongodb shell:  (trying to get a list of all account ids of a particular type that are members of any groups owned by a particular user)

```
groups.aggregate(
    {
        $match : {
            ownerId : ObjectId("XYZ"),
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
               from: "accounts",
               localField: "_id",
               foreignField: "memberships.groupId",
               as: "account"
             }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "account._id" : 1,
            "account.position" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$account"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "account.position" : "ZZZ"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id : 0,
            accountId : "$account._id"
        }
    })
```

Java version of the Aggregation:

```
MatchOperation match1 = Aggregation.match(
  where("ownerId").is(accountId));

LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
  .from("accounts")
  .localField("_id")
  .foreignField("memberships.groupId")
  .as("account");

// This doesn't work correctly on nested fields:
ProjectionOperation project1 = Aggregation.project(
  "studentAccount._id", 
  "studentAccount.position");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
  match1,
  lookupOperation,
  project1,  
  unwind("account"),
  match(where("account.position").is("ZZZ")),
  project().and("account._id").as("accountId"));
```

Comment: Can you share the domain types involved as well as the entire `Aggregation` not just the one project operation. In case of a typed `Aggregation` properties are mapped to field names.

Comment: @ChristophStrobl, I have added additional information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your aggregation work look like mongoshell your could try like this

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                match1,
                lookupOperation,
                // This's your project operation
                 new AggregationOperation() {
                    @Override
                    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                        Document project = new Document("$project",
                                new Document(
                                        "_id", "$account._id"
                                ).append("position", "$account.position")
                        );
                        return aggregationOperationContext.getMappedObject(project);
                    }
                },
                unwind("account"),
                match(where("account.position").is("ZZZ")),
                project().and("account._id").as("accountId")
        );
```

You can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57703112/10761696) in a more generic way

Comment: yes, I know I can do it this way.  I considered writing the entire aggregation as json (since that is how I develop the pipeline anyways) and parse it in to run, but I am trying to figure out how to do it via the Spring Aggregation API.